# Analog Java's Netty in Obj-C

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, netty

Is there a mechanism in Obj-C similar to Netty in Java?
Now i'm reading information about AsyncSocket and CFNetwork. But may be there are some libraries to work with network in iOS?
May main task is binding local port and depending on request/response load context in UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Use JUMP Framework with JUMPNetwork module: http://seqoy.github.com/jump/Docs/JUMPNetwork/html/index.html

Comment: Did you find the solution for decode/encode http. I am also looking similar for Netty for diverting TCP to UDP protocols in Transport Layer.

Comment: I downloaded the code and tried to run. But it is not compiling.
If I do some modifications then The project is compiling.

But whenever I write the below code,
JPPipeline *pipeline=[JPPipeline init];
Then It is giving the following error.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_Warn", referenced from:
      -[JPPipeline notifyHandlerException:withEvent:] in libJUMPNetwork.a(JPPipeline.o)
      -[JPPipeline sendUpstream:] in libJUMPNetwork.a(JPPipeline.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Even though I am using required frameworks, and files are placed properly on Compiler sources.

Can you please help me to compile the project and access the Pipeline object.